# structure pointer declaration giving error

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
struct node {
int data;
struct node  *next;
};
struct node * list,root;
list=NULL;
root=NULL;
```

Above is what I am trying to create in my program and my program when I compile gives error

```
kbc.c:8: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
kbc.c:8: error: conflicting types for ‘list’
kbc.c:7: note: previous declaration of ‘list’ was here
kbc.c:8: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
kbc.c:9: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
kbc.c:9: error: conflicting types for ‘root’
kbc.c:7: note: previous declaration of ‘root’ was here
kbc.c:9: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Here is the full program if some one wants to see I am just making a program to write a link list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
int data;
struct node  *next;
};
struct node * list,root;
list=NULL;
root=NULL;
struct node * create_node(int );
int main ()
{
int i,j,choice;
printf("Enter a number this will be root of tree\n");
scanf("%d",&i);
printf("Give us choice 1 to enter more numbers 0 to quit\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);
switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:break;

        case 2:break;
        }
}
// end of function main
struct node * create_node(int data)
{
struct node *temp;
t    emp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
return temp;
}
```

Comment: `root` is not a pointer. You may want `struct node *list, *root;`

Comment: My guess is that

list=NULL;
root=NULL;

should probably be done inside of main. Globals are a code smell... pass them as parameters.

Comment: @pmg I did it `struct node *list,*root;` still same error.

Comment: By the way, since `list` and `root` are "global" variables, they will automatically be initialized to `0` (`NULL`) if you write `struct node *list, *root;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you have declared one pointer and one structure.  Your declarations are equivalent to:

```
struct node *list;
struct node  root;
```

This is why the '`*`' indicating a pointer belongs with the variable name (*declarator* in standardese) and not with the type.

The other part of the problem is that you can only initialize a variable at global scope with a (constant) initializer; you cannot write assignments at global scope.

There are multiple ways to fix this:

```
typedef struct node *NodePtr;
NodePtr list = NULL, root = NULL;

struct node *list = NULL, *root = NULL;

struct node *list = NULL;
struct node *root = NULL;
```

Note that one of the many reasons for not using a `#define` in place of `typedef` is that:

```
#define NodePtr struct node *        // BAD!
NodePtr list = NULL, root = NULL;    // BAD!
```

creates exactly the erroneous situation in the question.

Addressing some of the error messages:

```
kbc.c:8: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
```

This is referring to the line:

```
list = NULL;
```

Because you are writing at global scope, this is interpreted as a variable definition, with no explicit type.  This is horrid style nowadays, but was allowed in original (pre-standard) C, using the 'implicit-`int`' rule to infer the type - which also explains some of the subsequent messages.  The 'implicit-`int`' interpretation was obsolescent in C89 and not officially supported by C99, but compilers still recognize it (with a warning at least in C99 mode).

So, this is interpreted as:

```
int list = NULL;
```

These messages are now explained:

```
kbc.c:8: error: conflicting types for ‘list’
kbc.c:7: note: previous declaration of ‘list’ was here
```

You have written code that the compiler must interpret as a second declaration of `list`.

```
kbc.c:8: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

And this is explained; since the second `list` is an `int` and `NULL` is a null pointer constant in this implementation (likely `#define NULL ((void *)0)`), there is a conversion from a pointer to an integer without a cast.

The second set of warnings apply to analogously to `root`.

Comment: actually when I used struct `node *list,*root;` then also I had the same error.How ever I used following now                                                   `typedef struct node * nodePtr;
nodePtr list,root;
list = NULL;
root = NULL;`  
and I still got the same error.

Comment: Some people do not like to hide the pointerness of a type behind a `typedef` :)

Comment: @pmg: Good point - I wondered whether to bring that out and decided not to.  I don't like hiding pointer-ness inside typedefs when (as here) I'm going to dereference the type to get at the data.  When the type is opaque, then I have no problem with a `typedef` hiding a pointer; I'm blissfully unaware of it.

Comment: @Registered User: you will continue to have problems while you try to write your 'initializer' separate from the declaration.  Inside the scope of a function, you can do that; at global or file scope, you cannot.  At global or file scope, you must initialize as you declare the variable.

Answer (score 3):

This is not OK at global scope:

```
struct node * list,root;
list=NULL;
root=NULL;
```

Try this:

```
struct node *list=NULL, *root=NULL;
```

The reason is that you can't put statements to execute (like `list=NULL`) outside of a function.

Comment: Yes you were right and I saw the error disappearing but why is that thing I mean why can I not put `list=NULL` outside of a function?

Comment: It's just not how C works.  In some languages (including most scripting languages), you can just put statements at global scope like that.  But in C (and many C-like languages), the global scope supports declaration (and even initialization) of variables, but you can't just write your whole program in the global scope.  That's what `main()` is for.